# Folium map KeyError ATA while saving

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, data-science, folium

when trying to save my map i get the following error

```
'KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-65c9bba51b6f> in <module>()
  7 # Create Folium plot
  8 #map.save('plot_data.html')
----> 9 map.save(outfile= "test.html")
KeyError: 'ATA'
```

this is my code, here i am trying to bind the pandas data frame and the json geometries to create an overlay for visualisation of data

```
import folium
import pandas as pd
country_geo  = './world-development-indicators/world-countries.json'
data = pd.read_csv('world-development-indicators/Indicators.csv')
hist_indicator = 'CO2 emissions \(metric'
hist_year = 2011
mask1 = data['IndicatorName'].str.contains(hist_indicator) 
mask2 = data['Year'].isin([hist_year])
stage = data[mask1 & mask2]
plot_data = stage[['CountryCode','Value']]
hist_indicator = stage.iloc[0]['IndicatorName']
map = folium.Map(location=[100, 0], zoom_start=1)
map.choropleth(geo_path=country_geo, data=plot_data,
         columns=['CountryCode', 'Value'],
         key_on='feature.id',
         fill_color='YlGnBu', fill_opacity=0.7, line_opacity=0.2,
         legend_name=hist_indicator)
map.save('plot_data.html')
```

Comment: If you post more code we can help you. It is not enough code.

Comment: @ EKis Byberi, sir can share the link of my jupyter notebook that has the code

Comment: No, the code must be here, in question.

Comment: @ElisByberi , thank you for your patience, i have added more codes

Comment: Please read carefully this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve I can not reproduce this error.

Comment: @ElisByberi if you have the data set and the packages then you should be able to reproduce the error

Comment: Check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38014480/python-folium-choropleth-map-keyerror-none